# Is it possible to get total count of employees and employees in each department in a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called employee like below:

```
emp      dept
----     ----
1         HR
2         Accounts
3         HR
4         Dev
2         Dev
```

It is possible for an employee to belong to more than one department, for example in the case of employee 2.

I want an output like this :

```
dept    empInDept   totalCountofEmp
 -----    ---------   ----------------
    HR       2            4
    Accounts 1            4
```

I can get a count of employees in specified departments like below:

```
select dept,count(*) as empInDept from employees where dept ='HR' or dept='Accounts' group by dept
```

But I am not sure if it is possible to create a **single** query where it is possible to get result of above `select` query and also get the overall distinct count of employees from this table.

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: a UNION query to combine the two queries together is the first thing which occurs to me

Comment: @ErayBalkanli I have edited my question with the expected output

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of your request:

```
create table #temp
(id int, value int)

insert into #temp values (1,2),(2,3),(1,5)

select id, count(Value), (select count(distinct value) from #temp) as X
from #temp
group by id
```

For your specific task, please try the following:

```
select dept,
       count(*) as empInDept 
       (select count(distinct emp) from employees) as TotalCount
from employees where dept ='HR' or dept='Accounts' 
group by dept
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. ´:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANSI/ISO standard `rollup` or `grouping sets`:

```
select dept, count(distinct emp)
from employees
where dept in ('HR', 'Accounts')
group by grouping sets (dept, ());
```

More databases support `rollup`, but the syntax can vary.  One method is:

```
select dept, count(distinct emp)
from employees
where dept in ('HR', 'Accounts')
group by rollup(dept);
```

Comment: will the rollup handle the `overall **distinct** count of employees`?

Comment: @arahman . . . Yes, `count(distinct)` works with `grouping sets` and `rollup()`.

Comment: Cool, I was just wondering as I have never tried count(distinct) with rollups. It was just for my knowledge :)